# How to process tag helper in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, tag-helpers, asp.net-core-tag-helpers, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc-2.1

I want to know in ASP.NET Core 2.2 if there is a way to invoke `TagHelper` through code? I have custom TagHelper

```
public class EmailTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public string MailTo { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.TagName = "a";        
        output.Attributes.SetAttribute("href", "mailto:" + MailTo);
        output.Content.SetContent(MailTo);
    }
}
```

Then in some `render` method in another class i want to use TagHelper to get corresponding markup

```
    public override void Render(string email)
    {
        var emailTagHelper = new EmailTagHelper();
        emailTagHelper.MailTo = email;

        // How do i pass TagHelperContext and TagHelperOutput            
        emailTahHelper.Process(........);

        //How do i get html string here            
    }
```

How do i process TagHelper though code here? Where would i get `TagHelperContext` and `TagHelperOutput` parameters and what method i need to invoke to get final html string?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by using `TagBuilder` instead of `TagHelper`.